# Why "Je viens de l'acheter" even if we have just bought "un livre"?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, genre, articles, élision

I thought it should be “*Je viens **du** acheter*”. Is it because “*acheter*” has a vowel at the beginning?

Comment: Note that *venir de* is followed by an infinitive, thus it's *acheter* and not *acheté*. Also, there's an *s* in *je viens* (most irregular verbs take an *s* in the first and second person in the indicative present singular).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*De le* becomes *du* only when *le* is an article, meaning "the". In this case *le* is a pronoun, meaning "it" (the book).

Comment: Notice that even when *le* is an article, if an elision is expected, *de le* becomes *de l'*.

Answer (score 10):

This sentence contains the particle *de* (part of the verb *venir de*) followed by the [personal pronoun](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronom_personnel) *l'* followed by the verb *acheter*. The usual form of this pronoun is *le* when referring to a masculine noun, and *la* when referring to a feminine noun. However, when the article is followed by a word that begins with a vowel, the pronoun is always elided to *l'*. The form *l'* exists for both genders.

This elision is also done when *le* or *la* is a [definite article](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_d%C3%A9fini): *le matin*, *la nuit*, *l'après-midi*. It is also done when *le* or *la* is part of a partitive article: *du pain*, *de la confiture*, *de l'eau*.

Now let's suppose the verb didn't start with a vowel: “*je viens de le vendre*”. Why don't we say “*je viens <s>du</s> vendre*”? There are two cases where *de le* contracts into *du*:

- When it is a [partitive article](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_partitif) (i.e. it means “some amount of”), as in *du pain*.
- When it the preposition *de* is introducing a noun group that begins with the definite article *le*, as in “*je descend du train*” (“*je descend de la voiture*”).

On the other hand, there is no contraction when *de* and *le* happen to be next to each other but they do not form a single unit. Here, *de* is part of the verbal compound *venir de* and *le* is a personal pronoun which forms a complement of this verb. There is no contraction when *le* is a pronoun: “*je viens de le vendre*”.

Comment: In *Je parle du vélo du facteur* hidden *de*-s are not partitive, but general prepositions. The true condition for the possible*du* contraction depends on the nature of *le*, which is either an article or a pronoun.

Answer (score 6):

You are right about the vowel part, consider these two examples:

> Du pain (instead of "de le pain")

But:

> De l'alcool ("alcool" is also masculine, yet "du alcool" is incorrect)

However, in your example the words "de" and "l'" are not linked at all, so you can't replace them by "du".

Consider these two examples:

> Je viens de manger. (*I just ate.*)

Here "de" isn't quantitative but is used to introduce another subsentence, here "manger".

> Je l'ai acheté. (*I bought it.*)

So they have no relation, and you can't say, for example:

> Je viens du lire. (wrong)

But you need to say:

> Je viens de le lire. (*I just read it.*)