# Quand utiliser « de le » au lieu de « du »?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, articles, élision

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why “Je viens de l’acheter” even if we have just bought “un livre”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1786/why-je-viens-de-lacheter-even-if-we-have-just-bought-un-livre)

Ma prof française au lycée me disais toujours « Il faut jamais dire *de le*» comme dans la phrase suivante:

> L'homme va faire du ski.

Cependant, il existe des cas où on dirait:

> J'ai hâte de le faire.

Qu'est-ce que c'est la règle pour décider entre « de le » et « du »?  Est-ce que ça marche pour « de les » et « des » aussi? Même « à le » et « au » et « à les » et « aux »?

Comment: Au temps pour moi, je n'avais pas vu cette question similaire...

Comment: @Gilles I understand why this question was closed as duplicate but it sucks that the original did not show up as a possible duplicate when I originally typed this.  Someone looking for an answer to this type of grammatical question would not easily be able to find the original.

Comment: @skeletank That's why we keep duplicates around: more search fodder. The automatic duplicate search has a hard time when the relevant words are *de le* and *du*, and not the rest of the example sentence.

Comment: @Gilles: that's why tags are useful. Sure, it requires a little time to fill them in…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans ton contre-exemple, *le* n'est pas un article défini, mais un pronom. La contraction ne s'effectue que dans le cas de l'article.

Le même raisonnement s'applique pour les autres contractions [*de les >>> des*], [*à le >>> au*], etc.

Exemples :

> J'ai fait un gateau. Je me prépare **à le** manger. (car *le* est un pronom remplaçant *le gateau*)
>
> Je parle **au** professeur. (forme contractée de [*à le* professeur], car *le* est ici un simple article)