# How to contract more than two consecutive contractable words?

Tags: élision, contractions

I'm thinking specifically of *jusque* + *à* + *le*. I'm pretty sure it becomes *jusqu'à le*, but I'm not positive. I suppose it could be *jusqu'au* or *jusque au* but I doubt it. In other words, for those in the know, is contraction left-associative?

Please don't *only* answer with regard to this example, but *also* with a general rule or with other examples if there is no general rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct expression is *jusqu'au*. I can't think of many cases with two contractions: *qu'au(x)*, more generally; also *d'aujourd'hui*. There's no special rule about them. If there are two places to contract, and they happen to involve the same word, so be it.

Note that apart from *au* and *du*, it's the end of a word that gets elided because of a following vowel; that doesn't affect the beginning of the word. In the case of *au* and *du*, the contraction doesn't affect what could happen to the preceding word, and no contraction is possible with the following word; however, *au* and *du* are not used when the next word begins with a vowel sound, so you could say that in that case, the contraction {*l'* + vowel sound} takes precedence over the contraction {à/de + le}.

Comment: *De le atelier* is a special case, it's not possible to contract in both places, and yields “de l'atelier”.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Hmm, good point. I was thinking of the rule “de le → du if the next word begins with a consonant sound”, but you can also phrase the rule as “de le → du unless le has been contracted into l'”.

Answer (score 3):

Most contractions are just simple elisions in French (one or two final letters are replaced by an apostrophe). Only four are non-trivial, each of them involve one preposition and one *article* (they don't apply [when *le* or *les* are pronouns](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5689/)):

- *au* = “à le”
- *aux* = “à les”
- *du* = “de le”
- *des* = “de les”

Those contractions are always performed, except when the article *le*, which is part of these compounds, can be elided first (example: *de l'abandon*, *à l'abandon*). This is actually the only point you should be careful about.

Now, because *au*, *à* or *aux* begin with a vowel, the word that precedes might also require an elision (but this was expected):

> Jusqu'au matin.
>   Jusqu'à l'aurore.
>   Jusqu'aux premières lueurs du soleil.

In very rare situations, several elisions could be chained.