# Tu te souviens du...? Ou souviens tu de....?

Tags: grammaire, verbes-pronominaux, interrogative

I am trying to ask a friend whether she remembers a person I was telling her about. "Do you remember Aaron?" but I'm not sure if I should say:"Tu te souviens du Aaron?" or "Tu souviens de Aaron?"

Comment: Is your question about the construction of the question or the choice of the correct préposition/article (“du” or “de”)?

Answer (score 8):

"souvenir" is a reflexive verb. You will always use it as "se souvernir".
So it would be :

> Tu te souviens d'Aaron ?
>   Tu te souviens de Stéphane ?
>   Te souviens-tu du zoo que nous avions visité ?
>   Est-ce que tu te souviens de l'histoire du garçon qui criait au loup ?

Please see source with the [full verb](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/se_souvenir.php)

**EDIT:**
As [@Stephane](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/79/st%c3%a9phane-gimenez) points out, you also misuse "de" and "du".
Note that "du" is the shortened version of "de le".
Here, you won't say "le Aaron", since it is a person, so you have to use "de".
Note that « de la » and « de l' » must **not** be shortened with **du** (as you see in my first and third examples).
For more information about "de" and "du", you may see on an other thread [this answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1788/7321) from [@Gilles](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/5/gilles)

Comment: There is a grammatical error (possible typo) in the second sentence. It should be "Te souviens-tu du zoo que nous avons visité?" using the past tense of the verb "visiter" ("Te souviens-tu du zoo que nous avions visité?" would also work).

Comment: @VonKar Indeed, it was a typo, thank you :)

Comment: Petite correction: "Tu te souviens d'Aaron"' et non "de Aaron"...

Comment: @BBBreiz Thanks. Here I wanted to point the use of "de" and didn't want to be confusing, I changed it :)

Answer (score 1):

You would most commonly say

> Tu te souviens d'Aaron?

if Aaron is a name (I don't know what Aaron is), but you can also say

> Te souviens-tu d'Aaron?

---

> Tu te souviens du Aaron

this means

> Do you remember the Aaron?

so it isn't correct

Comment: @Random when you say "do you remeber Drake?"

Comment: you cannot say "du Aaron" because Aaron begins with a vowel, so you must say "de l'Aaron".

Comment: Another precision: the first well-known Aaron in history was the brother of Moses, who became the first grand priest of the Hebrews.